# excluding dependency jars and decreasing build time maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have created pom.xml to build 2 jars. 1 will download data from hadoop so need Hive dependency jars (Java2Hive.jar ) anther jar Chat.jar doesnot need any of these dependencies. It may need few dependency like apache commons and apache utils. How to exclude and choose dependency jars?

Since It is adding all dependency jars, the size of both jars are 7MB and build time is always 6min. How to improve this performance and reduce the size?

here is my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HIVE</groupId>
  <artifactId>Chat</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_92</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1-cdh5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
    <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1-cdh5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.1</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.HiveJdbcConnection</mainClass>
          </manifest>
           </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>Java2Hive</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>

               <execution>
                    <id>build-b</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.ChatLog_Phase2</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>Chat</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>


            </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: You might specify the scope of the dependency see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: You were talking about two jars. Where is the second pom.xml?

Comment: Hm...you are creating two jar's which takes 6 minutes to build? Either your are doing very strange things or your hardware is very old..currently I'm maintaining a build which builds 1.5 million lines of code (800+ modules) producing about 4 GiB build artifacts etc. running about 6000+ unit tests in 6 minutes...This size depends on the usage of the things you include those assemblies ? Reducing the size can only be done by removing dependencies which can result in failing application ?